# 301 redirect a whole directory to a specific thread/link (same domain)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to add a 301 redirect to a whole directory and redirect every single link of this directory to a specific thread/post on the same domain.
I am using an apache server so i suppose i will have to edit the .htaccess

I want all the threads of this directory:

http://example.com/f73

To be redirected there:

http://example.com/f75/newthread-1990/#post333

I have read some different solutions and got confused :(

- Some guys recommend to use the "Redirect" command and other recommend the "RedirectMatch" command...
- I also read that the command should be different if the .htaccess is already edited and has some rewrite rules. Not sure if it makes sense or if i misunderstood, but at the moment i have added the following lines to the .htaccess:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htt://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^f73 /f75/newthread-1990/#post333 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May i ask why it's better to use RewriteRule? Which is the difference between RewriteRule/Redirect/RedirectMatch?

Comment: `RewriteRule` is more powerful and feature rich than `Redirect/RedirectMatch`. `RedirectMatch` also has regex support but doesn't have these flags like `NE` for no encoding etc.

Comment: I wish i had the power to vote up for you mate :) Let me ask you one more question, since you know so many things. Is there a difference in terms of SEO between RewriteRule/Redirect/RedirectMatch? Or all these 3 solutions they are more or less the same for the search engines and they will not "punish" my site with worst search results? I really need to start using this redirection, without damaging my site's SEO!

Comment: Your answer is definitely accepted! One more SEO related question. I normally hate deleting threads on my forum, because deleted threads give errors to the search engines. In this case, i want to delete the threads, because i don't want these threads to appear on the forum's search queries. Since the whole directory will have a 301 redirect to the new path, does it really matter (in terms of SEO) to delete this directory's threads?

Comment: If there is a 301 in place to redirect from old forum to new then SEO will be in good shape.